# Java regex, how to split on dot, whitespace, and keep quoted words together

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split my string on a dot, white space, and keep quoted words together. So for example say I have:

```
This "majestic world" is truly.awesome
```

it should result in:

```
This
majestic world
is
truly
awesome
```

Now, the regex I have so far is just `myString.split("\\. | ")`. I know that 
`("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'")` is supposed to split on white space and keep quoted words together. Now, I am not sure how to incorporate the dot escape there, and quite frankly that regex makes about as much sense as trying to flip a burger with your hands tied behind your back.

Edit:

the following is the reason why I want a better regex, since for me to handle keeping things within  quotation marks, I have to do the following:

```
if(listOfLists.get(i).get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("INSERT")) {
                        String insertInto = "";
                        boolean buildingString = false;
                        int k = 0;
                        while(k < listOfLists.get(i).size()) {
                            if(listOfLists.get(i).get(k).endsWith("\"")) {
                                buildingString = false;
                                insertInto += listOfLists.get(i).get(k);
                                break;
                            }
                            if(listOfLists.get(i).get(k).startsWith("\"") || buildingString) {
                                buildingString = true;
                                insertInto += listOfLists.get(i).get(k) + " ";
                            }
                            k++;
                        }
                        System.out.println("k is: " + k + " message is: " + insertInto);
                        dbCommands.appendToTable(listOfLists.get(i).get(k + 2), listOfLists.get(i).get(k + 3), insertInto);
```

Where the file i am parsing has a command as follows:

INSERT "John Smith" INTO college.students

Comment: I recommend that if you don't understand a regex, don't use it. Use what will be readable, maintainable, and extendible.

Comment: Well like I understand the concept behind it, but that was more like higher level abstract regex with regard to DFAs and NFAs, actually producing my own is quite complex for me. Since I feel like if I do use regex I will have a much easier timer than manipulating the code in strange ways to match.

Comment: Not sure but I'm having some fun trying it out using this nifty website:  http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will get you most of the way but you will still need to remove the quotes in a second step:

```
(\".*\"|[^\\s\\.]+)
```

IE:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\".*\"|[^\\s\\.]+)")
        .matcher("This \"majestic world\" is truly.awesome");
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll("\"", ""));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please explain what the ^ and s stand for? I want to say * is for white space, but i know in regular expressions (as in higher level) * means any. As to what ^ and s i can only guess that s means string?

Comment: The square bracket expression matches the characters defined within it. The caret "^" character effectively negates the expression. A "\\s" matches a whitespace character the "\\." matches a literal period. So "[^\\S\\.]+" matches one or more non-whitespace and non-period characters.